# Disable tab scrolling in Firefox 4 beta 10

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

is there a way to disable tab scrolling in firefox 4? So that i am able to view all tabs at any time (like in opera oder chromium/chrome). As far as i see the only posibilty comes with extensions like tab mix plus, that are not avaible for ff4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest checking about:config. There should be a browser.tabs.tabMinWidth option, or similar. Setting that to zero will allow the tabs to keep getting squished without falling back to tab scrolling.

Ref: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/quick-tip-disable-firefox-tab-scrolling/

Edit:

Having actually gone and installed Firefox 4 beta 10, it seems that's been removed. I searched around a little, and what finally worked was a userChrome.css modification.

Add to, or create userChrome.css in the chrome folder in your profile, and paste these lines in it:

```
.tabbrowser-tab {min-width: 016px !important;}
.tabbrowser-tab {clip-width: 016px !important;}
```

16 pixels is the width of the icon, thus tabs will never actually disappear, but you should be able to open many more tabs before scrolling kicks in.

Comment: This seems not to work. Neither does any of the solutions suggested in the comments of the linked article.

Comment: Edited to include a working solution. My bad, probably should have checked that before posting an answer.

Comment: Firefox 4 RC 2, I don't have a chrome folder anywhere within `~/.mozilla`

Comment: Worked for me on Firefox 16 (wow, we've advanced a lot of major version numbers in just over a year and a half)!  For help finding your userChrome.css file, see this question: http://superuser.com/questions/431289/where-is-userchrome-css