# Where is userChrome.css?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox

I am using Firefox 12 with Windows 7.

[**Here**](https://superuser.com/a/431278) it is recommended that I can use the `userChrome.css` file to make custom styles.

However neither the file nor the `chrome` parent folder seem to exist on my system.

For clarity, what would be a **full example path** to this file? Something like

```
C:\Users\Steven\AppData\...\<profile>\chrome\userChrome.css
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My confusion was between the `AppData\Roaming` and `AppData\Local`.

`AppData\Roaming` is the Firefox User Profile Directory

`AppData\Local` is the Firefox Temporary Directory

So the full path is

```
C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>\chrome\userChrome.css
```

[developer.mozilla.org/en/Runtime_Directories](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Runtime_Directories)

In Firefox you can also click <kbd>Help</kbd>, <kbd>Troubleshooting Information</kbd>, <kbd>Show Folder</kbd>

Comment: This is good to know. This is why I used the `AppData` variable in the path. `LocalAppData` is the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That path is correct. If the `chrome` folder or `userChrome.css` do not exist, you can simply create them yourself. For any changes to be applied, you must first restart Firefox. For this reason, I recommend the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on, as it is more flexible.

For Windows 7, the default path is:

```
%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>\chrome\userChrome.css
```

---

**Note**: I have chosen to use the `AppData` [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), as the full path can vary based on your system's configuration. If you installed Windows 7 on the `C:` drive and your home folder is `C:\Users\<user>`, then `%AppData%` expands to:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming
```