# Firefox, how to have very small tab size and no tab-scroll buttons

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, tabs, about-config

Both Chrome and Firefox introduced the Search tabs list menu.

[image]

In my view, this completely negates the need for the (very annoying imo) tab-scrolling feature of Firefox (i.e. when you have what they deem to be too many tabs for the view, `<` and `>` buttons appear on the tab line so that you can scroll left and right).
[image]

I would like to disable that functionality. I don't want to "turn Firefox into Chrome", I prefer Firefox for many many other reasons, but I want to remove the annoyance of the `<` / `>` buttons (honestly, it's one of the reasons that puts me off Firefox more than any other - I just see no purpose for these buttons, and not being able to visually see all tabs from one view is annoying).

I found that if you go to `about:config`, you can then search for `browser.tabs.tabMinWidth`, and adjust the size. In an article from 5 or 6 years ago, it said you can reduce this to 0, but I found this impossible, and an [article from 2019](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1253108) said that it is limited to a minimum of 50 pixels. There is also [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/238404/disable-tab-scrolling-in-firefox-4-beta-10) from 11 years ago that is redundant with respect to modern Firefox.

Is there a way to disable the tab scroll left/right buttons `<` / `>` and/or reduce the tab pixel width to '0' or '1'?

Answer (score 5):

1. type about:config into the address bar and then toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets into the search on that page. Turn the setting from false to true.
2. Find your user profile folder by typing about:support in the address bar.
3. Edit/create [chrome/userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html) in your profile and add these lines...

```
.tabbrowser-tab {
    min-width: initial !important;
}
.tab-content {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

4. Restart Firefox

Comment: Thanks Robert, however, I'm a little confused by step 3, userChrome.css in my chrome folder? Or does this mean the firefox folder? Is the file userChrome.css or userFirefox.css? I'm not sure how to proceed. I also have portable versions of Firefox on various computers, with no profile Firefox folders, how do I add this option on those?

Comment: Did you click on the link? It has more details. The file is named userChrome.css and if it exists is in a directory named chrome. By default neither the directory, nor the file will exist.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks, checking this solution out... I was wondering if Firefox had moved over to Chromium based on that wording there. I guess the "chrome" in userChrome.css refers simply to chrome as in "shiny stuff / extra features" as opposed to Chromium based browsers.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work as far as I can see. I followed this, and read the linked article, implemented it exactly as written (created the `chrome` folder and the `userChrome.css` etc). `<` and `>` buttons still there (after a reboot) when I go above about 20 tabs. I then went and added `browser.tabs.tabMinWidth` again down to `1` to see if that made a difference, but again, nothing. Whenever I go above 20 tabs, those really annoying `<` and `>` buttons appear. :(

Comment: I tried it locally and it does work for me. Did you do step 1, nothing happens if you skip that.

Comment: I did. I'm going to do a complete reset on my Windows now (been meaning to for weeks) and then I will try again and see what happens.

Comment: This did not work for me, however the answer below did.

Answer (score 2):

Had this same problem. The available solutions cause flickering where the tablist keeps trying to switch between scrolling and non-scrolling. Here's how I solved it:

1. In `about:config` set `browser.tabs.tabMinWidth` to *1*.
2. Add this style to `userChrome.css`:

   ```css
   .tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned]) {
     min-width: 1px !important;
   }
   ```
3. Install this user script:

   ```javascript
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name            noTabScroll
   // @author          blackle
   // @include         main
   // @startup         UC.noTabScroll.exec(win);
   // @shutdown
   // @onlyonce
   // ==/UserScript==

   UC.noTabScroll = {
     exec: function (win) {
       let {customElements} = win;

       const old_on_underflow = customElements.get('arrowscrollbox').prototype.on_underflow;
       customElements.get('arrowscrollbox').prototype.on_underflow = function (e) {
         if (this.id === "tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox") {
           e.preventDefault();
           return;
         }
         old_on_underflow.call(this, e);
       };
       const old_on_overflow = customElements.get('arrowscrollbox').prototype.on_overflow;
       customElements.get('arrowscrollbox').prototype.on_overflow = function (e) {
         if (this.id === "tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox") {
           e.preventDefault();
           return;
         }
         old_on_overflow.call(this, e);
       };
       customElements.get('tabbrowser-tabs').prototype._initializeArrowScrollbox = function () {
         return;
       };
     },
   }
   ```

A more detailed guide is on this page: https://suricrasia.online/firefox/